# Action-listener on Rowtoggle-ajax event in datatable gets incorrect parameter-value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable with a rowtoggler:

```html
<p:dataTable expandedRow="#{line.toggled}"
             value="#{cartController.getLines(agreement.id)}" 
             var="line" widgetVar="table" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
  <p:ajax event="rowToggle" 
          listener="#{cartController.toggleAndSaveLine(line)}" 
          disabled="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
  ...
</p:dataTable>
```

My goal is to keep track of which row that is toggled on the server side, so I call toggleAndSaveLine in my cartController on rowToggle. My problem is that no matter which one of the rows I toggle, the line-parameter in toggleAndSaveLine-method will always be the last element in the provided list of values, making it impossible to keep track of which row that was toggled. The strange thing is that I use the *var* `line` in other similar AJAX-calls and there it works perfectly.

Any ideas what might be wrong? I'm using PF6.

Comment: Most likely a bug.  Probably already fixed in later PF versions?

Comment: @Melloware Yeah that's my suspicion aswell. That is really unfortunate, since I cannot upgrade the PF version at the moment. (Huge application and managers have it planned for a future sprint)